# Is `clang-check` failing to honor `-isystem`?

Tags: c++, qt, clang-static-analyzer

For both Clang and GCC, the `-isystem` flag adds a "system" include path, which causes the compiler *not* to emit warnings related to code found in those headers.

However, running `clang-check` on my code, I see the following warning:

```
In file included from <myfile>.cpp:1:
In file included from <Qt-path>/gcc_64/include/QtCore/QCoreApplication:1:
In file included from <Qt-path>/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qcoreapplication.h:40:
<Qt-path>/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:235:16: warning: Potential memory leak
        return connectImpl(sender, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&signal),
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

...so it would appear that `clang-check` does not treat `-isystem` include paths differently from `-I` include paths. Am I misusing the tool or misinterpreting the output (i.e., is this actually a potential error in my code)? Is there another way to explicitly ignore errors from Qt headers when running `clang-check`?

Comment: *Is there another way to explicitly ignore errors from Qt headers when running `clang-check`?* So you have reasons to think potential memory leaks from `QObject` should be ignored? Can you share these?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I would expect *all* potential problems from system `#include`s to be ignored, because in general such `#include`s are from third-party code that can't be modified, and therefore those warnings are a distraction from any issues that the `clang-check` user *can* address.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi If there's a problem with *how `QObject` is used in **my** code*, then there should be some indication of that in the `clang-check` output, but the above output is the *only* output I get from `clang-check`.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Still wish I had more time to steer you back from this practice, though ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Er, if I *can't change* the code, what's the purpose of a warning for it?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I mean, if I were a Qt developer, obviously I'd want to see that warning, but in that case I'd be using `-I` instead of `-isystem`.

Comment: You're doing everything right, the warning is bogus, obviously clang-check does something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you also have to include the "QtCore" directory via-"isystem", in addition to just the base Qt include directory.  This is because Clang finds a more specific include (QT -Is the modules as well) and uses that.  See the [Clang Manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-in-system-headers) for -isystem information on how the includes work.

Effectively you want to do the following:

```
contains(QT,"core") {
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS *= $$join(QMAKE_INCDIR_QT, " -isystem", "-isystem", "/QtCore")
}
```

And repeat this for all standard Qt modules (Designer, Gui, Help, Network, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and arrived at this question via search engine.  So for anybody else like me; the answer is to use the -extra-arg twice!

For example

`./MyTool -extra-arg="-isystem" -extra-arg="my/system/include/path" myfile.cpp`

And you don't get all those warnings.

Comment: This seems specific to whatever tool you're using to *invoke* clang-check; what is `MyTool`?

Comment: No, the extra-arg handlers are processed by `clang::tooling::CommonOptionsParser` that your tool will use to setup llvm - it's common to all clang::tooling implementations.

Comment: Ah, so that includes running `clang-check` directly, since it's a Clang tool? My understanding when I wrote the question was that `clang-check` accepts all the same arguments as `clang` directly.