# Why is clang reporting warnings on my header despite the use of -isystem, while gcc reports none?

Tags: c++, c, clang

Slightly related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172832/is-clang-check-failing-to-honor-isystem) but not the same.

Using clang 7.0.1 on Arch Linux. I like clean code, so I want to enable all warnings and treat them as errors.

The problem is that I have some autogenerated files in my build that are not free of warnings, e.g.:

**generated/foo.h**

```
inline void foo(int unused) {  // warning: unused parameter 'unused'
}
```

**generated/foo.cc**

```
#include "foo.h"

// There is actual code here, but it doesn't matter.
```

Since these files are generated by a third-party tool, I cannot easily modify them, so I use `-isystem` to suppress all warnings from the `generated` directory.

I also have a main file that depends on the generated ones:

**main.cc**

```
#include "foo.h"

int main() {
  foo(42);
}
```

With gcc, I can compile this just fine, even with all warnings enabled.

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -isystem generated -omain main.cc generated/foo.cc
```

With clang, however, it fails to compile `generated/foo.cc`:

```
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -isystem generated -omain main.cc generated/foo.cc
In file included from generated/foo.cc:1:
generated/foo.h:1:21: error: unused parameter 'unused'
      [-Werror,-Wunused-parameter]
inline void foo(int unused) {
                    ^
1 error generated.
```

Adding [`--system-header-prefix`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-in-system-headers) does not help:

```
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -isystem generated --system-header-prefix=generated/ -omain main.cc generated/foo.cc
In file included from generated/foo.cc:1:
generated/foo.h:1:21: error: unused parameter 'unused'
      [-Werror,-Wunused-parameter]
inline void foo(int unused) {
                    ^
1 error generated.
```

What *does* help is to replace `#include "foo.h"` by `#include <foo.h>` in the generated ("DO NOT MODIFY") code. This is hardly a proper fix, but it provides a clue: I suspect that clang is somehow finding `foo.h` in the current directory `.` instead of scanning the include path, and of course `.` is not marked as a system include directory.

This is actually almost documented:

> A `#include` directive which finds a file relative to the current directory is treated as including a system header if the including file is treated as a system header.

However, it doesn't say what happens if the including file is not a header at all.

Workarounds that I can think of, none of which are great:

- Postprocess the generated files before compiling them. E.g. by adding `#pragma clang system_header`. Ugly, and tricky to do in a very portable way.
- Fiddle with the build system, CMake, to not enable warnings when compiling the generated `.cc` files. But this probably means I'll have to add a separate target for them, which means either duplicating lots of flags and configuration, or a DRY but more complex `CMakeLists.txt`.

I'd rather just set the right flags, like with gcc. Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you disable warnings using `#pragma` directives from inside those files or those including them? That's at least the approach I would take. And yes, that implies a compiler-specific `#ifdef` section.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The generated headers are included from inside generated sources, so this would require postprocessing.

Comment: Well, it _is_ recommended good practice to not leave unusued variables around. You should definitely have warnings enabled for this. Portable solution:

    `inline void foo(int unused) {
      (void)unused;
    }`

Comment: @Lundin It's in machine-generated code. I don't own the code generator.

Comment: Yes but it's still fishy code, so you shouldn't disable the warning. It works correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I underestimated CMake; this works without adding a lot of clutter:

```
set_source_files_properties(generated/foo.cc PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -w)
```